# Can I use 2 data extensions in 1 multi-step journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am creating a multi-step journey builder.

1. The entry point is configured as an API event.
2. The API event will be triggered once a week.
3. The journey contains 2 emails.
4. `not_purchased_customers_data_extension` is the main data extension for the journey.
5. Email 1 will be sent to all customers in the API call stored in `not_purchased_customers_data_extension`.
6. Email 2: will be sent after 3 days based on a decision. In this decision split, I want to evaluate a field in this `purchased_history_data_extension`**- is it possible to do that?** Based on the value in this `purchased_history_data_extension` email 2 should be sent or customer exits. I have looked around in marketing cloud builder and so far it doesn't seem possible but wanted to confirm this.

Also....can someone please help me understand the expected behaviour of the multi-step?
For example....

- In week 1, I have 20 customers who have gone through the journey and exited, however their information will remain stored in `not_purchased_customers_data_extension`.
- In Week 2 there is a new list of 50 customers dropped into `not_purchased_customers_data_extension` and I'm expecting only these new 50 customers to enter the journey.
- Those who existed in week 1 will not enter the journey regardless when they have exited the journey.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question - yes it is possible to evaluate a field in the second DE by [creating an Attribute Group and connecting DE#1 and DE#2](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_connect_data_extensions_for_decision_split_use.htm&type=5). Then it is up to you to understand how to settle up the connection.
In the end, you would be able to use DE#2 in the Decision Spit inside the Journey.

For the second question regarding the expected behaviour, not sure what is your doubt but you would need to think about [Contact Entry Mode](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_choose_a_contact_entry_mode.htm&language=en_US&type=5) that would affect on how your contacts would (re)entering or not the journey. For example, If you want to only accept unique contacts through the whole journey lifetime then choose the "No re-entry" option.